# Set CentreX and CentreY properties of CompositeTranform in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, silverlight-5.0

CentreX and CentreY refer to which transformGroup in WPF - 
SkewTransform/ScaleTransform/RotateTransform ??

This is the original composite statement :

```
<CompositeTransform CenterY="0.434" CenterX="0.499" ScaleY="1.14" TranslateY="-0.093"/>
```

I have transformed it in wpf as :

```
<TransformGroup>
     <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1.14" />
     <RotateTransform />
     <TranslateTransform Y="-0.093" />
     <SkewTransform />                                            
</TransformGroup>
```

I am not sure for which transform should I set the CentreX and CentreY properties.

Comment: Take a look at `RenderTransformOrigin`. I think that is what you are after.

Comment: TranslateTransform does not have a center and you don't seem to rotate or skew anything. Your question doesn't make sense. And note that the order of the children of the TransformGroup is relevant. It makes a difference if you first scale and then translate, or do it the other way round.

Comment: Then can you please tell me where would I place these properties : CenterY="0.434" CenterX="0.499" for the element ?? This CompositeTransform is for LinearGradientBrush and I am not able to find RenderTransformOrigin for it. I need to convert these styles from Silverlight to WPF.

Comment: ScaleTransform has a CenterX and a CenterY property, so obviously that's the place where you want to set these values.

Comment: Thanks.. Actually that's what I was confused about since not only ScaleTranform but RotateTransform  as well as Skew have these properties and these are quite new to me..
Anyways Thanks a lot !!